# What happen if $\mathbb E[X]$ is finite but $\mathbb E[|X|]=+\infty $?

Tags: probability

My teacher said that if $\mathbb E[X]$ exist but $\mathbb E[|X|]=+\infty $ then the expectation is not very well defined. I don't understand the concept. In what is it really a mistakes ?

**Q1)** For example, let $X$ s.t. $$\mathbb P\{X=(-1)^nn\}=C \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2},$$
where $C$ is a constant s.t. $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\mathbb P\{X=(-1)^nn\}=1$.

We have that $\mathbb E[X]$ is finite (since $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converge) but $\mathbb E[|X|]=\infty $ (since $\mathbb E[|X|]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty $. So, what's the matter with this kind of r.v. ?

**Q2)** By the way, if I consider $Y$ s.t. $\mathbb P\{Y=n\}=C\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$, where $C$ is s.t. $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\mathbb P\{Y=n\}=1$, we have that $\mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[|Y|]=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}<\infty $, but the sum is not absolutely convergent. So what could be this type of r.v. ? Is it also a problem ?

Comment: As far as I know $E(X)$ can never be finite (cannot exist) if $E(|X|)=\infty$ . In fact, $E(|X|)$ exists $\Leftrightarrow E(X)$ exists.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your examples as some probabilities are $<0$.

Comment: @Delta-u: Presumably the probability was supposed to be just $C/n^2$, with $C=6/\pi^2$.

Comment: Since probability theory is based on Lebesgue integration, the two conditions are equivalent since a Lebesgue integral exists and is finite if and only if the integral of the absolute value of the integrand is finite.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: As my example show for Q1), your assertion is wrong...

Comment: @Delta-u: Yes you right, so Q2) is wrong. Thank you :-)

Comment: Conditional convergence is abysmal for actual analysis which is why we usually require absolute convergence.

Comment: "What happen[s] if..." This case never occurs.

Comment: @Did: thanks for your orthographe correction (I'm not english native, sorry). Why do you say that this case never occur whereas Q1) is such an example ?

Comment: In Q1, contrary to what you seem to believe, E(X) **does not exist** (and furthermore you suggest some *negative* probabilities, which is absurd). Please check the definition of the expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the series
$$ \sum_{k-1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$
is only *conditionally convergent*. This means that in general *its sum changes* if you sum the same terms in a different order. In fact, by the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) you can get the sum to be *anything you want* by selecting an appropriate order to put the terms in.

A probability space does not generally come with any concept of a particular linear order of the outcomes that you can use to decide how to sum the contributions to the expectation.

Therefore I'd say that it is a considerable stretch to say that "$\mathbb E(X)$ exists" simply because the above series converges, when it does not converge absolutely.

Comment: so if $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\ell$, what would you consider, that the expectation is not well defined ? And thus we can't says that $X$ is almost $\ell$ ?

Comment: @MSE: Indeed I would not consider that random variable to have an expectation. Note that, as Cameron Williams observed, the usual _formal_ treatment of probabilities is based on Lebesgue integrals. Lebesgue integrals generalize summation of _absolutely convergent_ series, but a merely conditionally-convergent series does not correspond to any Lebesgue integral.